# jquery selector combination + each + count

Tags: jquery, html

What i want to do is to select all records from a table, only records from column 2 with category c

```
#SelectField_c_r1c2 (row 1 cell 2 category c) , #SelectField_c_r2c2 (row 2 cell 2 category c) ...
```

and count the number and use .each()

i was trying to use .size() and .each(), but its not working, see:
http://jsfiddle.net/ndr8wk44/

```
var select_rec_categ = "c";
var select_rec_col = 2

$('"[id ^=#SelectField_" + select_rec_categ + "_r][id $=c" +         select_rec_col+"]"').size();
$('"[id ^=#SelectField_" + select_rec_categ + "_r][id $=c" +     select_rec_col+"]"').each( function() {

alert($(this).val());
});
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues: The first issue is that you didn't close the single quote on the first segment on your statement. The other was that you were using `#` within your ID selector, but because you're using the attribute selector, you don't need to include the `#`.

This will get you the columns:

```
var cols = $("[id ^=SelectField_" + select_rec_categ + "_r][id $=c" + select_rec_col+"]");
```

So then to get the count you can do:

```
var count = cols.length;
```

Then to iterate them to access the values, do:

```
cols.each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: @user1000744 No problems glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

not sure to understand what you'r trying to do. maybe something like this?

```
var id = '#SelectField_' + select_rec_categ + '_r1c' + select_rec_col;

$(id + " option").each( function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ndr8wk44/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This would alert `3` then 3 empty value and the selected text (since there are not `value` attribute)

```
var select_rec_categ = "c";
var select_rec_col = 2;
var sel = "[id^=SelectField_" + select_rec_categ + "_r][id$=c" + select_rec_col+"]";
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($(sel).size());
    var str = '';
    $(sel).each( function(idx,el) {
        el = $(el)
        var opt = el.find(':selected')
        str += idx + ': value="' + el.val() + '" text="' + opt.text() + '"\n';
    });
    alert(str);
});
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/er1myezg/6/)